# Unable to import cls file to sql server 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i am trying to import cls file to sql server 2005. cell containing value with comma is not imported to sql server[image]

Rows 7 to 14 not import to sql server 2005

Answer (score 0):

Firstable check field types, do they set to appropriate type and length.
Second check the tring itself, does this string contain some special charachters?